# Find range by format and then change that format (not using the replace option)

Tags: vba, ms-word, find

Newbie Jan here with his first question

I am trying to understand the behavior of my vba code. The code is searching for words/sentences with a specific format. When found I would like to adjust these words/sentences by modifying the range that is returned. If I adjust the range as this
that does not produce any problem (loop continues). If I delete the returned range the loop also continues.

```
Dim myFind As Find
Dim myRange As Range
        
Set myRange = Application.ActiveDocument.Content
Set myFind = myRange.Find
        
With myFind
    .ClearFormatting
    .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineDouble
    .Font.Italic = True
End With
        
Do While myFind.Execute = True
    myRange.Font.Bold = True
    myRange.Font.StrikeThrough = True 
Loop
```

However If I adjust the format that is used in the search (myRange.font.italic = false) then the loop exit after the first found.

```
Dim myFind As Find
Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = Application.ActiveDocument.Content
Set myFind = myRange.Find

With myFind
    .ClearFormatting
    .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineDouble
    .Font.Italic = True
End With

Do While myFind.Execute = True
    myRange.Font.Italic = False  
Loop
```

Can someone help me understand why this happens? If I delete the range (`myRange.delete`) the loop  continues (which confuses me). It seems I cannot undo the formatting of what I am searching in this way... but deleting the range gives no problem. I tried to find documentation about this but I am unable to find information about my specific problem.

I have worked around this by selecting the range and then executing the next find and then modifying the selection. This works... but I would still like to understand what is happening.

P.S. This is just a part of the code. The code will be used to create some revisions. That is the reason I do not use the find/replacement options

Thanks!

**some extra context**

I am dealing with big word files and I want to automatically find 'specially formatted text' and modify this text automatically. Eventually I want the formatted text to become a track change/revision (that is also the reason I do not use the find/replace options). But I would first like to understand what is happening in my code. I understand that the .execute is returning a false and that this is the reason of the exit of the loop. I do not understand why .execute is returning a false while there are still other words/sentences in the document that have the format I was searching for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Find in VBA it is best to set `.Wrap = wdFindStop` to avoid getting into a continuous loop.

If you are not going to use `Replace` it is also good practice to assign the result of `Execute` to a variable (although there is a `Found` property it is considered unreliable).

Performing actions on the found range and then continuing the `Find` requires the use of `Execute` again in the loop. It is also necessary to collapse the found range so that `Find` can continue past it.

When the `Find` criteria are met the range is redefined to the found range. If you change the properties of that range so that they no longer meet the `Find` criteria `Do While myFind.Execute = True` evaluates as False, ending the loop.

The following routine works for all the conditions you mention in your question.

```
Sub FindFormatting()
  Dim findRange As Range
  Dim findSucess As Boolean
    
  Set findRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    
  With findRange.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineDouble
    .Font.Italic = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    findSucess = .Execute
    
    Do While .Found
      With findRange.Font
        .Italic = False
      End With
      'collapse range to continue
      findRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      findSucess = .Execute
    Loop
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Timothy for addressing my attention to the collapse part (and also the good practice tips)
I will try and read more why collapsing the found range allows that Find to continue.

Comment: @JanScholte - my assumption is that Find first evaluates the range to see if the criteria are met. If they are, and *only* if they are, it perhaps then checks if that match has already been processed and then moves on. That would explain the behavior you saw in the first part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

*This probably should be a comment, but I am too new to add a comment.*

I can verify that this happens on my system. To clarify, what you are trying to do is change the formatting for your targets to remove them from the search criteria after you have done your double-strikethrough and bold?

Your code is exiting the loop after the first pass to remove the Italics. That means it has finished the find. I can't explain this.

When I substitute the following for the code changing Italics, I get a message box for each instance found.

```
`MsgBox "Still in Loop"`
```

I'm still not clear on why you are not using the Replace function.

================== EDIT - ADDED IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT ==================

Try the following. It is going through the document multiple times but seems to work.

```
 `Sub replacer()
     ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63766819/ms-word-vba-find-object-by-format-and-then-change-that-format-not-using-the-rep
     Dim myFind As Find
     Dim myRange As Range
     Set myRange = Application.ActiveDocument.Content
     Set myFind = myRange.Find
     With myFind
      .ClearFormatting
      .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineDouble
      .Font.Italic = True
     End With
     Do While myFind.Execute = True
      myRange.Font.Bold = True
      myRange.Font.StrikeThrough = True
     Loop
     '
 StartOver:
     Set myRange = Application.ActiveDocument.Content
     Set myFind = myRange.Find
     With myFind
      .ClearFormatting
      .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineDouble
      .Font.Italic = True
      .Font.StrikeThrough = True
      .Font.Bold = True
     End With
     Do While myFind.Execute = True
 '      MsgBox "Still in Loop"
       myRange.Font.Italic = False
       If myFind.Found = True Then GoTo StartOver
     Loop
 End Sub`
```

I still have no explanation for why this is happening.

Comment: I am dealing with big word files and I want to automatically find 'specially formatted text' and modify this text automatically.
Eventually I want the formatted text to become a track revision (that is also the reason I do not use the find/replace options).

But I would first like to understand what is happening in my code. I understand that the .execute is returning a false and that this is the reason of the exit of the loop. I do not understand why .execute is returning a false while there are still other words/sentences in the document that have the format I was searching for.

Comment: I am editing my answer with code that seems long and clunky but seems to do what you want.

Comment: You should remove the meta commentary about your answer being a comment.  If you do not have the required permissions, to submit a comment, then you should not submit a comment as an answer.  Commentary submitted as an answer is typically deleted by the community.